# ios How to debug dynamic framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I created a dynamic framework, and I wrote a sample app that uses this framework.

I put bp in the dynamic framework code.
but, bp is not working.

What should I do?

**[*] current setting**

1. project : abc
2. target :

   - abc-dynamic-framework
   - abc-dynamic-sample-app (dependency: abc-dynamic-framework, Embedded Binaries: abc-dynamic-framework)
3. Generate Debug Symbols : All are YES
4. Strip Debug Symbols During Copy : All are NO

Comment: You are using workspace of the dynamic framework, have you embedded it.

Comment: @iOSTeam "abc-dynamic-sample-app" has embedded "abc-dynamic-framework". It runs well. only debugging of framework is not working. T.T..

Comment: you have to add your source code file to your project also means your workspace file or your project file and then you can debug it , it is still not clear so please let me know I will provide you steps also..

Comment: @iOSTeam "abc" project has "abc-dynamic-framework" target and "abc-dynamic-sample-app" target. and sources of dynamic framework is in "abc-dynamic-framework" target. Do you need more information? Need to add sources of dynamic framework to "abc-dynamic-sample-app"? T-T

Comment: @iOSTeam solved!! I made a sample that was debugged and compared it. The "deployment postprocess" option should be set to "No"!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Assume  that you have framework source code:
And you have app source code:

Your project name : project123
Framework name : frame123

**Steps:**

1. Drag the frame123.xcodeproj file to project123 and check it is
   expandable or not, If it is expandable so you can now directly use
   this framework in to your app.(1.png)
2. Add same framework to embedded binaries and check it is showing in
   linked framework and libraries , If it already there so remove from
   it and add it again.(2.png)

[image]

[image]